# xmlHttpRequest status = 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, amazon-web-services

I have a website (wagtail CMS) running at AWS at domain:8000 and my API running at domain:8801

On my webpage I try to get some info from API by using JS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set correctly at API, it's a django-based app)

Unfortunately the following code returns only xhr.status = 0 and empty responseText no matter what I try to access.

When I put domain:8000 at xhr.open('GET','http://domain:8000',true) everything works just fine, I see my html code.

```
function load() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain:8801/api/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( "ERR" ); --always ERR in browser
    } 
    else {
        alert( "SUCCESS" );
    }
}
```

On the API side I see all my requests, status=200 in server console.

Comment: The same-origin policy dictates that protocols, domains **and ports** must match, so there's no suprises here, it's not supposed to work, it's a security measure.

Comment: Doesn't the Access-Control-Allow-Origin allow that to be bypassed?

Comment: @arjabbar - if it's set correctly, it should, but seeing as it works with the same port, and not with different ports, it probably isn't set correctly.

Comment: @adeneo when I change url to http://google.com here is what I see in chrome console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domain:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. With my url it's just empty

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to use a callback function to catch the response from a request using the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Do something like this instead:

```
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert( "ERR" ); --always ERR in browser
    } else {
      alert( "SUCCESS" );
    }
  }
});
```

[Look here for docs and an examples on doing that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

Comment: When the third argument of `open()` is set to `true`, the request is synchronous, and obviously a callback isn't needed

Comment: @arjabbar  Guys, i overlooked this thing! Changed to false and now its working just fine

Comment: 3rd argument set to true makes the call asynchronous not synchronous. @massive_dynamic you should avoid synchronous xhr. Your issue is solved by a combination of this answer and waiting for xhr to complete before checking status i.e. xhr.readyState == 4

Comment: That's interesting. I never use that last argument. Having synchronous requests in Javascript is very strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for xhr.readyState == 4 before xhr.status is at all valid (actually I think it's valid at 3, but lets keep consistent with 99.999% of code in the wild)

```
function load() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain:8801/api/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert( "ERR" ); --always ERR in browser
            } 
            else {
                alert( "SUCCESS" );
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: `alert(xhr.status)` instead of 'ERR' ... what status are you getting ... you're sure the domain you are using allows CORS?